# How to pass parameters or cookies with requests in python?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, python-requests

I am facing a problem while extracting the cookies and parameters using

*inspect elements --> Network ( Firefox )*

And I am trying to pass it through my request

with this code:

```
import requests

cookies ={"_ga":"GA","cookid":"cookies","cookname":"username","id":"id_num","ider":"ider","PHPSESSID":"PHPSESSID","tb":"tb_num"}
params ={"Query string":{"sec":"8"},"Form data":{"chk[]":["on","on","on"],"sec":"8","add-final":""}}
url = 'https://url.com/add.php?sec=8'

r = requests.post(url, cookies=cookies, params=params)

print(r.cookies)
```

(i changed the cookies for safety)

and when it print the cookies it just returns this:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

Comment: Add the URL so that we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

`r.cookies` does not get you the cookies of the request, rather it gets you the cookies that were received in the response of the request.

To get the cookies that were sent,

```
r.request.cookies
```

Comment: No my friend, that's wrong. it do give the cookies but no cookies to show, your code is giving me an error.

Comment: Did you do, `print(r.request.cookies)`?

Comment: ايه يقلبي, سويت وماضبط :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be linked with the way you are sending the POST request, try replacing this:

```
r = requests.post(url, cookies=cookies, params=params)
```

with this:

```
r = requests.post(url, cookies=cookies, data=params)
```

Also, if you are trying to print cookies in the form of a dictionary you should be using:

```
print(r.cookies.get_dict())
```

hope this helps

Comment: @NabeelAl-Hamwi try replacing data=params with json=params